# Load completely with request in python (or other ways)

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, instagram

**Hi**
I was wondering if I can load the page completely with python, for example, a hashtag page form Instagram
there is code I tried but it wouldn't load completely 
Here's my code

```
import json
import re
import requests
x = input("Enter your hashtag: ")
response = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + x + '/?__a=1')
if response.status_code == 404:
    print('page not found')
    input()
    exit()
data = response.text
x = re.findall("\"shortcode\":\"[^\"][^\"][^\"][^\"][^\"][^\"][^\"][^\"][^\"][^\"][^\"][^\,]", data)
y = [i.split('"')[3] for i in x]
x = 0
z = len(y)
print(str(z)+' Posts found')
while x < z:
    print('\r' + str(x) + ' posts done', end="")
    data = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/' + y[x] + '/?__a=1')
    y[x] = data.text
    x = x + 1
print()
print('post link finished')
Usernames = []
Posts = []
Followers = []
Following = []
x = 0
while x < z:
    print('\r' + str(x) + ' Usernames done' , end="")
    data = json.loads(y[x])
    Usernames.append(data['graphql']['shortcode_media']['owner']['username'])
    x = x + 1
print()
print('Usernames finished')
print(len(Usernames))
```

I want to have more usernames like 100k or more if you can help me with other libraries it isn't important

Comment: the page only loads 80 results

Comment: This is probably due to how most pages now load additional content when you reach the bottom of the page. You would have to trigger that scrolldown or fire off the event handler that will load additional content.

Comment: How????????????